# public objects and ints in unity

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine

OK, fist off, I know very little about unity and C#. I was originally making this in javascript, but then converted it to c# and unity for various reasons. I'm making a monopoly simulator and I have a script that can play the entire game on its own, but it doesn't move any of the pieces on the board, it just constantly updates the values of the player's position and money and the status of all the properties. what I want to do is, for each player, get the position value from the player object, made with the following code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player
{

internal int money;
internal int position;
internal int jail;

public Player()
{
    money = 0;
    position = 0;
    jail = 0;
}

public virtual void addMon(int newMoney)
{
    money = money + newMoney;
}
public virtual int Pos
{
    set
    {
        position = position + value;
    }
    get
    {
        return position;
    }
}
public virtual int Jail
{
    set
    {
        jail = value;
    }
    get
    {
        return jail;
    }
}

public virtual int Mon
{
    get
    {
        return money;
    }
}
}
```

and match up their position with an array of (x,y) coordinates to move the player sprite to for each position.

the problem is that I don't know how to get the positions in a different script than it was made in. I tried making the Player objects public, but that made the rest of the code unable to change the values in the main code. how do I get the ints in a different class?

P.S.
here is the code that plays the game. It's not 100% done, but it shows the idea.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

public class boardmove:MonoBehaviour
{
// find all the card and property objects?
void Start()
{

    //create/initialize variables
    Random Random = new Random();
    int rand;
    int counter;
    int currentPlayer = 1;
    int move;
    int roll1;
    int roll2;
    int speeding;

    Player Player1 = new Player();
    Player Player2 = new Player();
    Player Player3 = new Player();
    Player Player4 = new Player();

    int startposition;
    int endposition;

    //create all positions as property objects
    Property[] buyList;
    buyList = new Property[40];
    buyList[0] = new Property(0, 0);
    buyList[1] = new Property(60, 2);
    buyList[2] = new Property(0, 0);
    buyList[3] = new Property(60, 4);
    buyList[4] = new Property(0, 0);
    buyList[5] = new Property(200, -1);
    buyList[6] = new Property(100, 6);
    buyList[7] = new Property(0, 0);
    buyList[8] = new Property(100, 6);
    buyList[9] = new Property(120, 8);
    buyList[10] = new Property(0, 0);
    buyList[11] = new Property(140, 10);
    buyList[12] = new Property(150, -2);
    buyList[13] = new Property(140, 10);
    buyList[14] = new Property(160, 12);
    buyList[15] = new Property(200, -1);
    buyList[16] = new Property(180, 14);
    buyList[17] = new Property(0, 0);
    buyList[18] = new Property(180, 14);
    buyList[19] = new Property(200, 16);
    buyList[20] = new Property(0, 0);
    buyList[21] = new Property(220, 18);
    buyList[22] = new Property(0, 0);
    buyList[23] = new Property(220, 18);
    buyList[24] = new Property(240, 20);
    buyList[25] = new Property(200, -1);
    buyList[26] = new Property(260, 22);
    buyList[27] = new Property(260, 22);
    buyList[28] = new Property(150, -2);
    buyList[29] = new Property(280, 24);
    buyList[30] = new Property(0, 0);
    buyList[31] = new Property(300, 26);
    buyList[32] = new Property(300, 26);
    buyList[33] = new Property(0, 0);
    buyList[34] = new Property(350, 35);
    buyList[35] = new Property(200, -1);
    buyList[36] = new Property(0, 0);
    buyList[37] = new Property(350, 35);
    buyList[38] = new Property(0, 0);
    buyList[39] = new Property(400, 50);

    string[] position;
    position = new string[41];
    //initialize all possible board positions
    position[0] = "Go";
    position[1] = "Mediterranean Ave.";
    position[2] = "Community Chest";
    position[3] = "Baltic Ave.";
    position[4] = "Income Tax";
    position[5] = "Reading Railroad";
    position[6] = "Oriental Ave.";
    position[7] = "Chance";
    position[8] = "Vermont Ave.";
    position[9] = "Connecticut Ave.";
    position[10] = "Visiting Jail";
    position[11] = "St. Charles Place";
    position[12] = "Electric Company";
    position[13] = "States Ave.";
    position[14] = "Virginia Ave.";
    position[15] = "Pennsylvania Railroad";
    position[16] = "St. James Place";
    position[17] = "Community Chest";
    position[18] = "Tennessee Ave.";
    position[19] = "New York Ave.";
    position[20] = "Free Parking";
    position[21] = "Kentucky Ave.";
    position[22] = "Chance";
    position[23] = "Indiana Ave.";
    position[24] = "Illinois Ave.";
    position[25] = "B.&.O. Railroad";
    position[26] = "Atlantic Ave.";
    position[27] = "Ventnor Ave.";
    position[28] = "Water Works";
    position[29] = "Marvin Gardens";
    position[30] = "Go To Jail";
    position[31] = "Pacific Ave.";
    position[32] = "North Carolina";
    position[33] = "Community Chest";
    position[34] = "Pennsylvania Ave.";
    position[35] = "Short Line Railroad";
    position[36] = "Chance";
    position[37] = "Park Place";
    position[38] = "Luxury Tax";
    position[39] = "Boardwalk";
    position[40] = "In Jail";

    Card[] chance;
    //initialize all chance cards
    chance = new Card[17];
    chance[0] = new Card(0, "Advance to Go (Collect $200)");
    chance[1] = new Card(24, "Advance to Illinois Ave. - If you pass Go, collect $200");
    chance[2] = new Card(11, "Advance to St. Charles Place - if you pass Go, collect $200");
    chance[3] = new Card(-1, "Advance to the nearest Utility. if unowned, you may buy it from the bank. if owned, throw dice and pay owner ten times the ammount thrown.");
    chance[4] = new Card(-2, "Advance to the nearest Railroad and pay owner twice the rental to which he/she is otherwise entitled. \n If Railroad is unowned, you may buy it from the bank.");
    chance[5] = new Card(-2, "Advance to the nearest Railroad and pay owner twice the rental to which he/she is otherwise entitled. \n If Railroad is unowned, you may buy it from the bank.");
    chance[6] = new Card(50, "Bank pays you dividend of $50 (Collect $50)");
    chance[7] = new Card(10, "Get out of Jail Free - This card may be kept until needed.");
    chance[8] = new Card(3, "Go back 3 Spaces");
    chance[9] = new Card(40, "Go to Jail. - Do not pass Go, do not collect $200");
    chance[10] = new Card(0, "Make general repairs on all your Property - For each house, pay $25 - for each hotel, pay $100.");
    chance[11] = new Card(15, "Pay poor tax of $15");
    chance[12] = new Card(5, "Take a trip to reading Railroad - If you pass Go, collect $200 (Advance to reading Railroad)");
    chance[13] = new Card(39, "Advance to Boardwalk - Take a walk to the Boardwalk");
    chance[14] = new Card(50, "You have been elected Chairman of the Board - Give each Player $50");
    chance[16] = new Card(100, "You have won a crosword competition - Collect $100");



    //initialize community chest cards
    Card[] comChest;
    comChest = new Card[16];
    comChest[0] = new Card(0, "Advance to GO (collect $200)");
    comChest[1] = new Card(200, "Collect $200 (Bank error in your favor)");
    comChest[2] = new Card(50, "Pay $50 (Doctor's fee)");
    comChest[3] = new Card(50, "Collect $50 (From sale of stock)");
    comChest[4] = new Card(0, "Get out of jail free.");
    comChest[5] = new Card(41, "Go to jail (Advance to jail)");
    comChest[6] = new Card(150, "Collect $50 from every Player - Grand Opera Night");
    comChest[7] = new Card(100, "Collect $100 - Holliday fund");
    comChest[8] = new Card(20, "Collect 20$ (Income Tax Refund)");
    comChest[9] = new Card(10, "Collect $10 (It's your birthday)");
    comChest[10] = new Card(100, "Collect $100 (your bonds mature)");
    comChest[11] = new Card(100, "Pay $100 (Hospital Fees)");
    comChest[12] = new Card(150, "Pay $150 in School tax");
    comChest[13] = new Card(25, "Collect $25 consultancy fees.");
    comChest[14] = new Card(0, "You are assessed for street repair - pay $40 per house - pay $115 per hotel");
    comChest[15] = new Card(10, "Collect $10. You won second place in a beuty pagent.");




    /* determine which Player's turn it is 
     * escaping jail
     * move their piece on the board according to their roll 
     * allow time for current Player to trade Property
     * allow Player to buy un-owned Property
     * make Player pay rent on Property if already owned (monopolies, houses, hotels)
     * special spaces and cards(luxury tax, community chest, chance, rail roads, appliances)
     * second turn on doubles
     * speeding rule
     */

    if (currentPlayer == 1)
    {
        //reset speeding rule and die rolls
        speeding = 0;
        roll1 = 1;
        roll2 = 1;
        // before turn begins, ask Player if they want to trade property or buy/sell houses and hotels.

        //if Player is in jail
        if (Player1.Pos == 40)
        {
            roll1 = 0;
            roll2 = 0;
            // ask if they want to pay, use a card, or roll doubles

            //if the Player uses a card or pays, set their position to visiting
            if ()
            {
                Player1.Pos = 10;
            }
            //if the Player chooses to roll, let them roll and have their turn continue if they succeed
            else
            {
                //get and read roll inputs
                if (roll1 == roll2)
                {
                    // Player takes their turn
                    Player1.Pos = 10;
                }
            }
        }

        if (roll1 != 0 && roll2 != 0)
        {
            do
            {
                // get read roll inputs
                move = roll1 + roll2;
                startposition = Player1.Pos;
                endposition = startposition + move;
                speeding++;

                //if the Player reaches the end of the board
                if (endposition >= 40)
                {
                    endposition = endposition - 40;
                }
                //passing go
                if (endposition <= startposition)
                {
                    Player1.addMon(200);
                }
                //set new position
                Player1.Pos = endposition;

                //buying, paying rent, and taxes
                if (buyList[endposition].getown().Equals("none"))
                {
                    if (buyList[endposition].getprice() > 0 && Player1.Mon >= buyList[endposition].getprice())
                    {
                        //ask Player if they want to buy property. 
                        //if yes
                        if ()
                        {
                            Player1.addMon(-buyList[endposition].getprice());
                            buyList[endposition].Own = "Player1";
                        }
                    }
                    if (buyList[endposition].getprice() == 0)
                    {
                        if (position[endposition].Equals("Communtity Chest"))
                        {
                            //check and reset deck
                            counter = 0;
                            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
                            {
                                if (comChest[i].Use == 0)
                                {
                                    counter++;
                                }
                            }
                            if (counter >= 16)
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
                                {
                                    comChest[i].reset();
                                }
                            }

                            //pull community chest card
                            do
                            {
                                rand = Random.Range(0,15);
                            } while (comChest[rand].Use != 1);

                            //card effects
                            if (rand == 0)
                            {
                                Player1.Pos = 0;
                            }
                            if (comChest[rand].Text.Contains("Advance to"))
                            {
                                //pass go rules
                                startposition = Player1.Pos;
                                //set new position and pass go rule
                                Player1.Pos = comChest[rand].Num;

                                if (Player1.Pos <= startposition)
                                {
                                    Player1.addMon(200);
                                }

                            }
                            else if (comChest[rand].Text.Contains("Pay"))
                            {
                                Player1.addMon(-(comChest[rand].Num));
                            }
                            else if (comChest[rand].Text.Contains("Collect"))
                            {
                                Player1.addMon(comChest[rand].Num);
                            }
                            else if (comChest[rand].Text.Contains("Get out of jail"))
                            {
                                // give Player get out of jail card
                            }
                            else if (comChest[rand].Text.Contains("street repairs"))
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
                                {
                                    counter = 0;
                                    if (buyList[i].getown().Equals("Player1"))
                                    {
                                        Player1.addMon((buyList[i].Hotel) * -100);
                                        Player1.addMon((buyList[i].House) * -25);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (position[endposition].Equals("Chance"))
                        {
                            //check and reset deck
                            counter = 0;
                            for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
                            {
                                if (chance[i].Use == 1)
                                {
                                    counter++;
                                }
                            }
                            if (counter == 17)
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
                                {
                                    chance[i].reset();
                                }
                            }
                            //pull chance card
                            do
                            {
                                rand = Random.Range(0,16);
                            } while (chance[rand].Use != 1);

                            if (chance[rand].Text.Contains("Advance to"))
                            {
                                Player1.Pos = chance[rand].Num;
                            }
                            else if (chance[rand].Text.Contains("Collect"))
                            {
                                Player1.addMon(chance[rand].Num);
                            }
                            else if (chance[rand].Text.Contains("Pay"))
                            {
                                Player1.addMon(-chance[rand].Num);
                            }
                            else if (rand == 8)
                            {
                                endposition = endposition - 3;
                            }
                            else if (rand == 9)
                            {
                                speeding = 3;
                            }
                            else if (rand == 10)
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
                                {
                                    counter = 0;
                                    if (buyList[i].getown().Equals("Player1"))
                                    {
                                        Player1.addMon((buyList[i].Hotel) * -115);
                                        Player1.addMon((buyList[i].House) * -40);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else if (rand == 14)
                            {
                                Player1.addMon(-3 * chance[rand].Num);
                                Player2.addMon(chance[rand].Num);
                                Player3.addMon(chance[rand].Num);
                                Player4.addMon(chance[rand].Num);
                            }
                            //include pass go rules
                        }
                        //paying income tax
                        if (position[endposition].Equals("Income Tax"))
                        {
                            if ((Player1.Mon / 10) > 200)
                            {
                                Player1.addMon(-(Player1.Mon / 10));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Player1.addMon(-200);
                            }
                        }
                        //paying luxury tax
                        if (position[endposition].Equals("Luxury Tax"))
                        {
                            Player1.addMon(-75);
                        }
                        //going to jail
                        if (position[endposition].Equals("Go To Jail"))
                        {
                            //speeding rule will send Player to jail
                            speeding = 3;
                        }

                    }
                    else if (!"Player1".Equals(buyList[endposition].getown()))
                    {
                        //add code for paying rent
                    }

                }
            } while (roll1 == roll2 && speeding < 3);
            //Repeat turn if Player rolled doubles and Player not speeding
            if (speeding == 3)
            {
                //send Player to jail
                Player1.Pos = 40;
            }
        }
        currentPlayer = 2;
    }
    else if (currentPlayer == 2)
    {
        //movement code
    }
    else if (currentPlayer == 3)
    {
        //movement code
    }
    else if (currentPlayer == 4)
    {
        //movement code
    }

}
void Update()
{
    //set all Player locations on board to locations in code
    //transfer property cards from card bank to Players
}
}
```

and here is the code where I am trying to get the player1 position value. it's a real work in progress, but it's what I got.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player1Move : MonoBehaviour {

GameObject playerIcon;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    int PlayerPos = (FindObjectOfType<boardmove(Player1Move.getPos())>);
    Vector2[] positions = Vector2[40];
    positions[0] =new Vector2(6,-6);
    positions[1] = new Vector2();
    positions[2] = new Vector2();
    positions[3] = new Vector2();
    positions[4] = new Vector2();
    positions[5] = new Vector2();
    positions[6] = new Vector2();
    positions[7] = new Vector2();
    positions[8] = new Vector2();
    positions[9] = new Vector2();
    positions[10] = new Vector2(-6,-6);
    positions[11] = new Vector2();
    positions[12] = new Vector2();
    positions[13] = new Vector2();
    positions[14] = new Vector2();
    positions[15] = new Vector2();
    positions[16] = new Vector2();
    positions[17] = new Vector2();
    positions[18] = new Vector2();
    positions[19] = new Vector2();
    positions[20] = new Vector2(6,6);
    positions[21] = new Vector2();
    positions[22] = new Vector2();
    positions[23] = new Vector2();
    positions[24] = new Vector2();
    positions[25] = new Vector2();
    positions[26] = new Vector2();
    positions[27] = new Vector2();
    positions[28] = new Vector2();
    positions[29] = new Vector2();
    positions[30] = new Vector2(-6,6);
    positions[31] = new Vector2();
    positions[32] = new Vector2();
    positions[33] = new Vector2();
    positions[34] = new Vector2();
    positions[35] = new Vector2();
    positions[36] = new Vector2();
    positions[37] = new Vector2();
    positions[38] = new Vector2();
    positions[39] = new Vector2();
    positions[40] = new Vector2();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that is giving you trouble? I.e. the portion of code where you are trying to access the coordinates.

Comment: From "I don't know how to get the positions in a different script than it was made in", it seems like you're trying to use C# and javascript in the same project. If so, please see [this page](https://answers.unity.com/questions/25070/c-scripting-and-javascript-in-the-same-project.html). If not, please try to state more clearly what it is you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

so I answered my own question after some more research. uhhh... I now realise I asked my question rather poorly, but I found I could get the Player1.position value from boardmove in PLayer1Move with the following code:

```
 void Update () {
    GameObject board = GameObject.Find("Board");
    boardmove movescript = board.GetComponent<boardmove>();
    int playerpos = movescript.Player1.position;
```